# HTML - Get consistent height across inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I am creating a horizontal navigation with an icon and text for each navigation item. I am running into an issue with items that contain two lines of text vs one. 
I have tried modifying the padding and height of the div that extends higher than the others, but to no avail. How can I modify this to achieve a consistent height across all navigation items regardless of lines of text?

View the fiddle: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/odcn1t7m/6/)

```
<div id="dashboard">
    <a class="actions" href="#">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-users"></i> <br />Employees
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="actions" href="#">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i> <br />Check Stats
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="actions" href="#"">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-table"></i> <br />Generate Census
        </div>
    </a>
    <a class="actions" href="#">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> <br />Send Forms
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="actions" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteClientModal">
        <div>
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <br />Delete
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

.actions:first-child div {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.actions:last-child div {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.actions > div {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #223a5c;
  border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0 -6px 20px 0;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.actions > div:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.actions > div i {
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: check flexbox ...

Comment: For the fastest way, add "height: 80px; vertical-align: top;" to the .actions > div CSS. But that could cause other problems later on in certain cases. (Note, the "height" can be whatever you want it to be that fits your content.)

Comment: @mrunion thank you, does the trick for now

Answer (score 2):

A flexbox solution might look something like this:

```css
#dashboard {
  display: flex;
}

div:first-child>.actions>div {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

div:last-child>.actions>div {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.actions>div {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: #223a5c;
  border: 1px solid #d6d8db;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.actions>div:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.actions>div i {
  width: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="dashboard">
  <div>
    <a class="actions" href="#">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-users"></i> <br />Employees
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="actions" href="#">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-pencil-ruler"></i> <br />Check Stats
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="actions" href="#">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i> <br />Generate Census
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>

    <a class="actions" href="#">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> <br />Send Forms
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>

    <a href="#" class="actions" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteClientModal">
      <div>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <br />Delete
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```